# Resize a view using scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a problem with UIScrollView.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40,320,500)];
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 120)];
```

and I overide scrollView

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   [mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 120 - scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

Everything is ok but it's not smooth when scroll and resize mapView. Is there a better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other views above your mapView, inside the scrollView? I assume here that the mapView is inside the scrollView.

Comment: Yep, mapView is a subView of scrollView

Comment: Tell me if i'm wrong. You are trying to achieve something like the checkin view in the facebook iOS app, where the map is resized as the user scrolls to the bottom of the list of locations?

Comment: You'r right, I do something like that, everything is okie but the scrollview not smooth

Answer (score 1):

Resizing views in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method is a taxing task. Also `scrollViewDidScroll:` doesn't always get called, not for each change in offset, at least.

A better way to do it would be, set the frame of the `MKMapView` once, which is large enough to cover more than the visible portion of the `scrollView`. You add your list of locations **above** the `mapView`.

Then in the `scrollViewDidScroll:`, set the `center` of the `mapView` such that it appears as if the `mapView` is resizing. What I did in my case, was change the `center` of the map as the offset changed. Something like:

```
mapView.center = CGPointMake(mapView.center.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y + DELTA);
```

DELTA here is a value you will have to get by hit-and-try., to keep the center of the map (user's location, I suppose) between the top border of your list, and the top of the scrollView.

EDIT : In my case, DELTA was the half the change in offset (respecting BOTH negative and positive values).

Comment: I have try it. it look better. it's best practice, isn't it?

Comment: It was the closest I could achieve. If I find something more optimized, I'll add it in an edit. But in the meantime, if this helps, accept it. :)